# Why are some items from Zoo not indexed in Smart Search?

Tags: smartsearch, zoo

Smart Search and Zoo are working as expected in 95% of Zoo items.  However, something strange is happening with the remaining 5% causing them not to work.

I have items with the text `1,251,647` that index perfectly, but I have items with the text `1,275,618` that do not work.

I already noticed that the expression `1,275,618` is not in the `##_zoo_search_index` table.

Anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried reindexing?

Comment: Yes. But the problem was not run smart search index. The problem was when the item was saved and Zoo and at this moment dont save the content in ## _ zoo_search_index

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

The problem was "multiple" repeatable element entries.

I changed:

\plugins\system\zoo_zlelements\zoo_zlelements\elements\downloadpro\downloadpro.php

from:

```
public function getSearchData() {
    $hits = $this->get('hits', 0);
    return $hits;
    return implode(', ', array($this->get('title'), $this->get('value')));
}
```

to:

```
protected function _getSearchData() {
    // clean html tags
    $value  = $this->app->object->create('JFilterInput')->clean($this->get('title', ''));
    return (empty($value) ? null : $value);
}
```

Comment: You can prevent page bumping and inform the "system" that your issue is resolved by awarding your answer the green tick.